# Masonry on Meteor won't take effect

Tags: javascript, meteor, masonry

I'm trying to run [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) on Meteor but I can't get it working. I'm sure everything's in place:

http://cryptostage.meteor.com/

My certainty is supported by the fact that if I Save the web page from the online version (as above) to my desktop and run it from there, Masonry works. In fact, this same version is also functional here:

https://cryptopal.s3.amazonaws.com/meteor-try/cryptopals.html

What am I missing?

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="pals" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options="{ &quot;itemSelector&quot;: &quot;.pal&quot; }">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pal col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><img class="pal-pic" src="./cryptopals_files/cryptopal.png">
      <div class="name-key"><p class="username"><strong>Matt</strong></p>
        <strong>Key ID</strong>
        <a class="key-id"><span class="smaller-text">Get public key» </span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your code if you seek a decent answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what to provide. Since Masonry works on one site, which is a Saved copy of the other live site, I suspect that the problem is somewhere I'm probably not looking, within the labyrinthine tangle of Meteor JS code. All that I can think to provide is typical Masonry setup code which works in one place and not elsewhere. Do you think that would help?

Comment: I think you should initialize masonry via JS in the rendered callback, this works fine for me.

Comment: Yes that works. I still find it unpleasantly puzzling that HTML selector initialization doesn't work. There must be some conflict somewhere and it may come to haunt me again. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, with your suggestion, it works locally, which it didn't before, but still not online. Here's a fresh deploy: http://cryptostager.meteor.com/ I'm smelling a rotting fish in there somewhere. Varying shades of functioning.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a timing issue related to when isotope kicks in vs when images are loaded that meteor exposes. What worked for me was to use imagesLoaded and then to transfer the items into the isotope container:

```
Template.home.rendered = ->
  $(document.body).imagesLoaded ->
    $('#isocontainer').isotope
      layoutMode: 'masonry'
      itemSelector: '.card'
      masonry: columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
    Meteor.setTimeout (->
      $('#isocontainer').isotope 'insert', $('.card')
    ), 500
```